# Java: Writing Text to a File from Multiple Methods in a Class WITHOUT a main() Method

Tags: java, printwriter

I am currently dead in the water with a Java programming problem that seemed somewhat simple at first to do! I am trying to write text to a file from MULTIPLE methods in a class that does NOT contain a `main()` method, unlike other answers of this type question have used.

So... A quick outline of what my program is currently doing:
My program has one class (with the `main()` method obviously) that reads a text file stored on the disk, and passes sections of the text to certain methods in another class (second file in the project) to simply write the passed text to a text file. Each method in the class without the `main()` method needs to write the string passed to them to THE SAME file.

Why am I having trouble? I can easily write text to a file from ONE method in the class without the `main()` with `FileWriter`, but in order to have all of my other methods to write to the same file, I would need to make `FileWriter` global. I have tried to make it global, but then when I save text after another method saved text, it just rewrites the file to the latest text written.

My current class without the `main()` method:

```
package ADIFTOCSV;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class createADIF {

    static File file;
    static FileWriter fw;
    static BufferedWriter writer;

    static void init() throws IOException {
        file = new File("/Users/Colin/Desktop/Myadif.txt");
        fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        writer = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    }



    static void storeDate(String datez) throws IOException {

        writer.write("<QSO_DATE:" + datez.length() + ">" + datez); <<----NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
    }

    static void storeFreq(String freqz) throws IOException {

        writer.write("<FREQ:" + freqz.length() + ">" + freqz);
        writer.close();
    }

    static void storeMode(String modez) {

    }

    static void storeBand(String bandz) {

    }

    static void storePower(String pwrz) {

    }

    static void storeTime(String timez) {

    }

    static void storeCall(String callz) {

    }

    static void storeRstSent(String rstsentz) {

    }

    static void storeRstRcvd(String rstrcvdz) {

    }

    static void storeComments(String commentsz) {

    }
}
```

Each of these methods needs to write the `String` passed to them to the SAME file.

`storeDate()` is the first method to be called, therefore it writes text to the file first. However, when `storeFreq()` is called, it's text completely replaces the text written by `storeDate()`. This is obvious because I am forced to create a new FileWriter object in each method in order to write text. I cannot put `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());` outside the method to make it global; errors arise.

Am I missing something? Help is much appreciated. If any questions arise, or clarification is needed, please just ask!

Comment: your trouble is only created on your mind. Try running your program and report if you get any error.

Comment: Please provide the code how you actually create and use the PrintWriter

Comment: How about you present the code that you actually tried.

Comment: @BjörnKautler No problem! I will edit the code. I used to have the PrintWriter code in there, but since it didn't work in my project I got rid of it. I will add it in

Comment: I guess my answer is already your solution. ;-) But currently it is mainly based on guessing what you were doing. *g*

Comment: Yep, what I wrote in my answer already, but now its clear to other readers

Comment: @BjörnKautler Thank you for being on this thread! I have added in the code, and ran it  once more..... same problems. I have also added some more explanation on exactly what happens

Comment: What is "errors arise"? Becaust that is what you need to do as I wrote in my answer. Also, you don't need to do `createNewFile()` the writer will automatically create it. And you also don't need to do `getAbsoluteFile()`

Comment: @BjörnKautler Thank you for your answer! If I put either the `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());` OR the `BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fw);` outside the method, I get this error:  "Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define explicit constructor"

Comment: Well, then do so. Create a constructor, create your writer there, and change your methods to being non-static. Using overly many static methods and stuff is not very object-oriented. ;-)

Comment: @BjörnKautler I have created a constructor. However, even in the constructor, the `writer` is local, and cannot be used outside of the constructor. Usually I would need to create a new object of the constructor, but I am not sure how I could use objects to write text to a file. Thank you for your help, and I think I am getting close! :)  (New code in original question)

Comment: You have to declare the variables as instance variables of course. Just the creation of the new objects and assigning to the variables happens in the constructor.

Comment: @BjörnKautler Thank you for the clarification (sorry I'm a beginner programmer in high school :-)) The updated code is above. I am receiving a Null Pointer Exception when I run the program on the line that it is commented on above.

Comment: Change 
'void createADIF() throws IOException {'
to
'static void init() throws IOException {'

Should do it

Comment: @Herter Thank you for the help! Unfortunately, I am still getting that Null Pointer Exception with static void init() throws IOException

Comment: What are you passing to the method because your code is running fine here. - Remember to call the #init() method before the other methods!

Comment: @Herter I am passing the methods regular Strings. That's it. I have updated the code above to the latest edits

Comment: @24GHz Remember to call the init method before calling the other methods :)

Comment: no, `createADIF()` was fine, but you must not have a return type (`void` in your case). With a return type it is not a constructor but a method.

Comment: @Herter Duh, sorry. I called the init method from my main method. Now it is throwing me this junk:    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Comment: After storeFreq the stream is closed of course as you close it. But remove that statics again and change init back to createADIF as I wrote above

Comment: I really don't see a point in using a constructor here when the class only contains static methods. Surely a init method is sufficient? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3):

You have to create the writer outside the methods.
Just defining the file outside is not enough.
If you recreate a writer to the same file in each method, of course it will overwrite.
The `File` instance is just a pointer to the file.
The writer is the "actual handle" that you need to reuse.

And be aware that you have to close the writer if you are finished with writing.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you scrap the class with the static methods and instead create a normal "File Write Handler" class which has a constructor where you can pass the File and writer to intialize the file writing classes and let that class handle all the writing to the file such that you can call a method like this:

```
FileWriteHandler.writer("<FREQ:" + freqz.length() + ">" + freqz);
```

and soforth for the rest you want printed. And finally call

```
FileWriteHandler.close();
```

Would be much cleaner and you could even make an interface for that class such that you can replace the FileWriterHandler with f.ex. a DatabaseWriteHandler or something like that.